# Any way to know if .htaccess is enable?

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting

any way to know if .htaccess is enable? I cannot read the httpd.conf file in my shared server.

I have access through ssh. My hosting provider uses cPanel Accelerated.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2):

What about just putting a `.htaccess` somewhere which alters some readily-observable settings and look whether they have been changed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading a sample .htaccess file (e.g. with a single simple redirect rule) and check if it works.